# How to calculate the address of a function using the base address of ntoskrnl.exe

Tags: hex, offset, windbg, ida

This is what I have determined thus far on a test machine:

1. base address of ntoskrnl.exe is 0xFFFFF802C8803000
2. using IDA the address of the imagebase is 0x0000000140000000
3. using IDA the address of the function is  0x00000001401422D0
4. the offset (3 subtract 2) is determined to be 0x1422d0
5. the function address is determined to be 0xFFFFF802C8803000 + 0x1422d0 = 0xfffff802c89452d0
6. Windbg says the address is 0xfffff802c89454d0

Is the above calculations correct ? Please tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: There's no reason your calculation shouldn't work. Are you sure you are disassembling exactly the same version that you're debugging? on Windbg do a `lmvm nt` then look at `Checksum` and `ImageSize`; open the binary file (that you disassembled, the image path is at the very beginning of the code disassembly in IDA) with a PE parser then check `SizeOfImage` and `Checksum` from the `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER`, they should match.

Comment: @Neitsa thank you. The base address of ntoskrnl.exe calculations in (1) were determined programmatically and it matches what Windbg provides. I ran the command lmvm nt in Windbg however in IDA I was not able to locate the two details namely sizeofimage and checksum.

Comment: Or you can just check that both binaries - the one debugged and the one disassembled -- have exactly the same version number (nb: to see both of the aforementioned fields you'll need to have a program that can parse PE files).

Comment: @Neitsa thank you again. IF you post your comments in an answer I will accept it. I was working with two different versions of ntoskrnl.exe one version for Windbg and the other version with IDA Free.

Comment: Glad you solved it! Thanks, but nah; you can definitely answer the question yourself and accept it; it's more about problem solving than anything else on my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution thanks to **Neitsa**. I was working with two different versions of ntoskrnl.exe one version for Windbg and the other version with IDA Free.